# Application to including, extending html document without server www

Tags: html

I'm front-end developer and in work I use Twig with Symfony2 on Apache server. But now I have to make mockups in HTML, CSS on my interaction computer-human course on university. I need some application to able to including other html file in html file, extending html file with other html file - something similar like in Twig include and extend features. Does something like that exist?

I'd rather don't use html frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) - but this requires a server (hence the name !!)

Then you could, for example add a header to each page:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

*Apache, nginx, lighttpd and IIS are the four major web servers that support this language.*

Your other option would be to use JavaScript and [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to pull in other content post load.